# What are the laws on using a company's logo in journalistic coverage?

Tags: united-kingdom, trademark

We have a non-commercial (academic) blog, and are writing a post about a commercial company.

The post is not especially flattering, for context.

Can we use the company's logo to illustrate the blog post, or can the company legally complain about this?

Answer (score 1):

I am not a lawyer - I'm just offering an opinion based on 20+ years of running a UK Ltd and being a news/research junkie  (FT, Bloomberg etc).

I believe you can use a logo so long as you are not implying a relationship exists between the two of you.

My bigger concern is if you write something that is discovered to be false - My understanding is if you were sued, you would have to prove that you published your article in good faith, believing everything you said was true. If you could not prove to the court that you had performed sufficient due diligence, you could be held liable. I presume you are publishing under your own name, and not under an entity (like a Limited Company) thus if you lost, the company could kill your credit history).

If you still want to proceed, make sure the post is dated, make sure you reference the sources of your information where possible. Make sure an opinion is an opinion and not misread as a fact.

Comment: You can't be prosecuted for writing something false about a company.  You can only be sued.  (Also, credit histories usually last 6 years, not 1 in the UK).

Comment: I was sure you were wrong Martin, but you appear to be more right than wrong http://www.trustonline.org.uk/understand-judgments-fines/ccjs-and-county-courts/county-court-judgment-records-how-long-ccjs-stay-on-record I have edited my answer. *It might be that we are both right*, just different type of debt (b2c and b2b credit law varies). One of the Irish bankers prosecuted claimed to resident of Northern Ireland. The BBC article I read said this was controversial, since he would have clean credit after a year, as opposed to Ireland where his credit history would be tainted far longer.